# Error in GetCapabilities WMS 1.3.0 geoserver, how to solve?

Tags: geoserver, cesiumjs

Error in GetCapabilities WMS 1.3.0 geoserver.
[image: Here is an error]

[image]

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 6869 at column 17: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I want to add data from geoserver to CesiumJs through wms.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine (in unnamed module @0x4c04c9c4) cannot access class sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.java2d.pipe to unnamed module @0x4c04c9c4 [in thread "qtp674483268-24"]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine.getInstance(RenderingEngine.java:129)
at java.desktop/sun.java2d.pipe.LoopPipe.<clinit>(LoopPipe.java:49)
at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SurfaceData.<clinit>(SurfaceData.java:450)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.initIDs(Native Method)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.<clinit>(WToolkit.java:195)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(Win32GraphicsEnvironment.java:60)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:34)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:93)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:84)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:106)
at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1182)
at org.geoserver.wms.map.ImageUtils.prepareTransparency(ImageUtils.java:162)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.renderRules(BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java:327)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.buildLegendGraphic(BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java:265)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.buildLegendGraphic(BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java:77)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.PNGLegendOutputFormat.produceLegendGraphic(PNGLegendOutputFormat.java:41)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.PNGLegendOutputFormat.produceLegendGraphic(PNGLegendOutputFormat.java:21)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.LegendSampleImpl.createNewSample(LegendSampleImpl.java:178)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.LegendSampleImpl.getLegendURLSize(LegendSampleImpl.java:156)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleLegendURL(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:1661)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleLayerStyles(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:1281)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleLayer(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:1220)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleLayerGroup(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:1563)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleLayerGroups(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:1419)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleLayers(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:834)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.handleCapability(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:626)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer$Capabilities_1_3_0_Translator.encode(Capabilities_1_3_0_Transformer.java:331)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$XMLReaderSupport.parse(TransformerBase.java:1054)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:485)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$Task.run(TransformerBase.java:287)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:121)
at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:103)
at org.geoserver.wms.capabilities.Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.write(Capabilities_1_3_0_Response.java:43)
at org.geoserver.config.CapabilitiesCacheHeadersCallback$RevalidateTagResponse.write(CapabilitiesCacheHeadersCallback.java:138)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
... 112 more
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Also what's at line 6869 would help

Comment: I changed the logging but it didn't worked(

Comment: Please provide the exception/error logs *as text*, don't display screenshots.

Comment: One thing to check if the aforementioned XML document is well structured.

Comment: are you running on Java 17? if so you need to read https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#running-on-java-17

Comment: I tried in Java 8, 11, 17, and 20. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that, when you use Java 17 there is file in webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib called marlin-0.9.3.jar . Full path is webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib called marlin-0.9.3.jar. Delete marlin-0.9.3.jar and your problem will be solved. More information you can find here https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#running-on-java-17

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. I'm on a Macos. The solution ended up being to install and use Java 11. I had tried version 17 (which the documentation suggests) and 19, but Java 11 did the trick.

Steps:

1. Find your current version `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and what versions are available on your system. It will look something like:

```
) /usr/Libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
19.0.1 (arm64) “Oracle Corporation” - “Java SE 19.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19. jdk/Contents/Home
17.0.8 (arm64) “Amazon.com Inc.” - “Amazon Corretto 17" /Users/jason/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.8/Contents/Home
15.0.10 (arm64) “Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 15.46.17" /Users/jason/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-15.0.10/Contents/Home
‘/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19. jdk/Contents/Home
```

2. Note that I was missing a Java 11 option. Install Java 11. Here's [where I downloaded Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html).
3. Once installed, run `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and you should see something like:

```
) /usr/Libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
19.0.1 (arm64) “Oracle Corporatior - “Java SE 19.0.1" /Library/Java/JavavirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
17.0.8 (arm64) “Amazon.com Inc.” - “Amazon Corretto 17" /Users/jason/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.8/Contents/Home
15.0.10 (arm64) “Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 15.46.17" /Users/jason/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-15.0.10/Contents/Home
11.0.19 (arm64) “Oracle Corporation” - "Java SE 11.0.19" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
```

4. Then open your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, or whatever you use to set environment variables and add a line to export your `JAVA_HOME`.

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

5. Be sure to check and see that you are not already exporting `JAVA_HOME`.
   If you are, change it to Java 11. If you are not, add the following new line:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)"
```

6. Save and exit your `~/.zshrc`.
7. Either close the current terminal window and open another, or use `source ~/.zshrc` to run the updated export.
8. Check your java version with `java --version`

```
) java --version
java 11.0.19 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1949-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.19+9-LTS-224, mixed mode)
```

9. Restart your geoserver.